# Too many inactive SYSMAN sessions in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

I have an Oracle 10g DB instance which is newly created. In this instance, I have imported a older dump from the same Oracle server. After importing, when I start the server I have noticed that users are not able to connect to the database.

While monitoring the sessions,  there are too many inactive SYSMAN sessions  and the count is increasing by the minute.

I am trying to understand the root cause for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identified the root cause and resolved the issue. For the DB instance, Enterprise Manager Database control was running. SYSMAN was waiting for something in the Enterprise Manager Database Control.

Once the Enterprise Manager Database Control is closed, the issue is resolved and the number of SYSMAN sessions are normal.

Command to stop Enterprise Manager Database Control:

```
./emctl stop dbconsole
```